# Is it possible to access a track's comments from the track's ID end point via Soundcloud API?

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

Via Javascript, I would like to gain access to all of a track's comments through the track ID end point? Something like ...

```
SC.get("/users/199197/tracks/100513066/comments", function(comments) {
        for (var key in comments) { 
            console.log(key, comments[key]);
        }
    });
});
```

I am looking for a `comments` object that is associated with each track. All I can find is a `comments_count` property associated with each track.

**Is there a** `comments` **object associated with each track?**

**If yes, then how to access it?**

**If no, then how can one access all the comments that were made on a single track?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to request `tracks/100513066/comments` without the `/users/:user-id` part.